# Getting last day of the current month

Tags: date, smarty

I can get the last day in php using  `cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 03, 2014);` function and then assign it to view. But I want to know is it possible to get the last day in current month using smarty `date_format` function?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can solve this only using the [`date_format`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl) function. I wouldn't do it anyway, since this put way too much application logic into the template.

But... if you want to do this anyway, just add a [template function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl) to get what you want.

PHP:

```
$tpl = new Smarty();
$tpl->registerPlugin("function","lastdayofmonth", "smarty_function_lastdayofmonth");
$tpl->display('your_template.tpl');

function smarty_function_lastdayofmonth($params, Smarty_Internal_Template $template) {
    return date("Y-m-t", strtotime($params['date']));
}
```

Smarty:

```
{assign var='datevar' value='2014-03-06'}
{lastdayofmonth date=$datevar}
```

Output:

```
2014-03-31
```

Keep in mind, this is just an easy example. There are more than one way to use plugins within Smarty.